# trabajando con mysql select

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-workbench

Quiero poner a la izquierda las columnas que estoy seleccionando de la tabla authors,junto con las columnas seleccionadas de las otras tabla,por qué me da error??

```
SELECT authors.au_ID AS id,authors.au_lname AS lastname ,authors.au_fname AS firstname, 
FROM authors 
LEFT JOIN authors ON titles.title AS title,publishers.pub_name AS publisher;
```

No me aparece ningún error solo una x al lado, ¿tendría que crear una tabla puente para poder hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Cuál error? ¿Cuál X? ¿De qué hablas? ¿`authors left join authors`? ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Muestra unos datos de ejemplo, la salida que obtenes o el error, y la salida que te gustaria obtener. Asi como esta, la pregunta es poco clara. Mira [ask]. Y mejora el titulo por favor.

Comment: Quiero una tabla con las siguientes columnas (las tres primeras son de una tabla llamada authors)(la siguiente de otra llamada tittle)(y la ultima de una tabla llamada publishers)ID/ LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME/TITLE/PUBLISHER No me genera ningun error,simplemente cuando ejecuto aparece una x en un cuadrado rojo a la izq de mi codigo y nada mas,